# How to change image button transparency programmatically?

Tags: android, imagebutton

How to set the transparency of the image button programmatically in android? I am creating dynamic image buttons on the fly.

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to change a button with the following:

```
btnMybutton.getBackground().setAlpha(45);
```

Answer (score 3):

**ImageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)** Should solve the problem.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29

> Set the background to a given Drawable, or remove the background. If
>   the background has padding, this View's padding is set to the
>   background's padding. However, when a background is removed, this
>   View's padding isn't touched. If setting the padding is desired,
>   please use setPadding(int, int, int, int).

Answer (score 2):

I like this:

```
imageButton.setImageAlpha(alpha_value); //alpha_value between 0...255
```